# updating page with jquery renders javascript function useless?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have this page where the user select an item and a php file will return a table with a few buttons on each cell but when I click on it the js function is not called.

this is the js function

```
$('#deleteRow').on('click',function(evt)
{
    console.log('triggered');

}
);
```

This is the php echo

```
echo "
<tr>
  <td>$name</td>
  <td>$startData  $startTime</td>
  <td>$endDate $endTime</td>
  <td id='action-buttons'><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary pull-right'  id='deleteRow' ><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i> </button></td>
  <td id='action-buttons'><button class='btn btn-primary pull-right' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></i> </button></td>
   <td><label id='1'><input id='check' type='checkbox' name='switch' class='checkbox' $activeBool /><div class='switch' ></div></label></td>
</tr>


";
```

and this is the way I place it on the page (this is the success function fo the ajax post)

```
 success: function(result){
               $('#content-table tbody').html(result);

             }
             });
```

I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: good call it was javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are registering the `click` event on something that doesn't exists yet.

Try this:

```
$(document.body).on('click','#deleteRow',function(evt)
{
    console.log('triggered');
});
```

**Update:**

As **ratiorick** mentioned, if you have a same id name and you want to get the handle of the one that you actually clicked, you can do something like this:

```
$(document.body).on('click','button[id^=delete]',function(evt)
{
    console.log('triggered');
});
```

`'button[id^=delete]'` basically says that every button whose `id` stars with `delete`.

Comment: Thanks man that worked. I guess it was something like that. :)

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help :)

Comment: I doubt that will work as you expect - check my post below .. Just trying to save you a few headaches as you will always end up deleting the last row. regardless of what button you press because of the ID ( jquery would just use the last found ) - If you only have 1 row, yes that will be fine, but i doubt that will be the case...

Comment: That will work, but i  still think the best solution would be to use a class.  With that beign said, this is solution to get around the issue if you had no other choice, so i will up vote this one.

Comment: it's actually working perfectly I actually set the the row id to the button and that way I can pass it to the php file as for security concerns it one id of many.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues.... 1 is that you are using an ID - in a place where you should be using a class... Change "#deleteRow" to ".deleteRow" - you could just bind the event handler in the success callback function like so
update the HTML TO this ( you should only use ID if there is 1 element ) otherwise use a class...

Update the HTML - ( also update the rest of these duplicated IDs )

```
  <td id='action-buttons'><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary pull-right deleteRow' >
```

And then attach the event handler in the callback function

```
success : function(result){
    $('#content-table tbody').html(result);
    $('.deleteRow').on('click',function(evt){
        console.log('Is it working now?'); 
    });
}
```

Comment: Is the proper way to uses a class for this? then what are id normally used for? thanks for the help.

Comment: An Id should be used when there is only a single element and that ID is unique... You will most likely end up with hard to find bugs if you start using Ids and duplicating them on the page.

Comment: This would still remove or trigger the last one if that is what you were trying to avoid with this solution.

Comment: If you are going to try to output something like you are, and targeting a group of elements - you should use a class instead.

Comment: how do you figure that? I was just commenting that there were more than just the issue of binding the event before it existed on the page.